# MySQL to search articles that match a search string a user types in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'stories' with some stories. The pertinent columns are 'title' and 'storyBody'. I have created a web page where users can ask freeform questions... like 'how can I protect my privacy?'.

What is the best MySQL approach to use to fetch a group of 5 or so stories that might best relate to the question?

I'm considering something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM stories
        WHERE MATCH (title, storyBody)
        AGAINST ('how can I protect my privacy?' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Is NATURAL LANGUAGE better than BOOLEAN?

Comment: This does not sounds like an appropriate task for a relational database.  Period.

Answer (score 0):

Whether `BOOLEAN` or `NATURAL LANGUAGE` is better is really something you'll have to decide, based on the needs of your application (or, if you want to do a query expansion search). Of course, you could also offload the responsibility of searches to another tool such as [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/), or switch to another RDBMS with (arguably) better full-text search capabilities, such as [Postgres](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/) (supports stemming, n-grams, etc.)